# Trigger button's click event when user types in textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to trigger button's click event when user types something in textbox. I have written the following textbox control and JQuery:

```
<asp:textbox id="description" runat="server" class="myclass">
<asp:Button id="btnApply" runat="server">

$(function () {
    $(".myClass").keyup(function (event) {
        $("#<%=btnApply.ClientID%>").click();
    });
});
```

When i enter first character in the textbox, the click event of button is triggered. But when i continue typing in the textbox the click event of button is not triggered on each key press.
If i use keypress or keydown same issue is there along with textbox value is not retained. while when using keyup, the textbox is retained.

Comment: you need .trigger("click") .A simple search would have thrown many such results.

Comment: @roshan: not true. `.click()` calls `trigger("click"`) internally. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click

Comment: @Mayur: is your page under inside updatepanel? unless this won't make sense.

Comment: @naveen thanks for awesome the link. Bookmarked !

Comment: why do you need `$("#<%=btnApply.ClientID%>")` instead of `$('#btnApply')` ?

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz: its framework related. it kinda muddles the id

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger as shown below,

```
<asp:textbox id="description" runat="server" class="myclass">
    <asp:Button id="btnApply" runat="server">

    $(function () {
        $(".myClass").keyup(function (event) {
            $('#btnApply').trigger('click');
        });
    });
```

Also, add the click event and its functionality for the button.

Answer (score 0):

include it inside your document.ready

$(document).ready(

```
$(".myClass").on('keyup',function (event) {
    $("#<%=btnApply.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
});
```

You can aslo change "keyup" by "change" if you want to fire your event once the text edition has been finished